# Error while building simple OMNET++ project

Tags: clang, omnet++, clang++

I'm receiving the following error while building my OMNET project. It's a simple project which includes 5 source nodes, 1 loadbalancer and 2 sink nodes. However, upon building the project,I receive the following error after the build is at 86% completion. (I'm using their IDE)

Error:
make MODE=release all
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /bin/sh: -c: line 1:` echo Creating executable: out/clang-release//lab_1_lastest(2).exe'
make: *** [Makefile:96: out/clang-release//lab_1_lastest(2).exe] Error 2
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

I'm pretty lost as to what to do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure that the path of your project does not contain a space.

Comment: I assume that round brackets are not allowed in the project name, try to rename `lab_1_lastest(2)`